# method with parameter in unknown js function issues

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to protect a part of my js code wrapping my code with an Unknown function.

I have edit my function to change

```
function banana(url) {}
```

to method

```
banana: function(url){ },
```

when I try to call my function banana in another function i try to use

```
this.banana(url);
```

but i have this error:

```
TypeError: this.banana is not a function
```

Full code:

```
(function (){
  var url_test = "./add_user.php?opt=get_user&token=<?php echo $token; ?>";
  if (typeof $.customfnc == 'undefined')
     $.customfnc = {}

  $.customfnc.get = {
      setup: function (){
        var url = "google.ca";
        this.banana(url);
      },
      banana: function (url){
         console.log("my url: " + url);
      };
   };
 };

  // on ready render data
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $.customfnc.get.setup();
  });
})(jQuery);
```

thanks for your help!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ue26Lo3t/1/ - looks fine

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that the scope of 'this' is not exactly what you might think it is.

The way I have handled this particular issue in the past is to add

```
var self = this;
```

Outside of the object that is attempting to self reference. This may impact how you have set up youre .get() object though.

```
$.customfnc.get = function(){
    var self = this; 
    self.setup = function (){
        //....
       self.banana(URL)
    }
    self.banana = function(url){
         //...
    }
}
```

Comment: Good Point. except that i can't push a variable like that. only method can be init like that. Variable make an error if i do that like that. SyntaxError: missing : after property id

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, does my edit help at all?

Comment: its make sense that the scope is the problem, i'm pretty sure thats the bug or a partial of the bug because during my test, I try to call a function through a $(el).submit(function (){}) too and i got the same issue, But your code doesn't work. I have an error on the variable line. I think you can't call like that a variable in that type.. into the "$.customfnc.get" i can only init a method and not variable. Variable need to init outside.

Comment: What error are you getting on the variable declaration?

Comment: SyntaxError: missing : after property id